# Find a list in a binary tree scheme 2

Tags: scheme, racket

Write a function in Scheme that receives as input argument list cedulas (identification) of students, a binary search tree with instances of the student structure and returns a list of instances of the student structure, where the identification of the list of students is in the binary search tree.

example:

This is the binary tree

```
(make-árbol-bin  
(make-estudiante 5 "35889188" "Victor" (make-fecha 10 6 1991) "calle 67 con cra 20" "4444444")  (make-
árbol-bin  
(make-estudiante 2 "6457234" "Manuel" (make-fecha 12 10 1992) "calle 56 con cra 33" "5555555")   (make-árbol-bin 
   (make-estudiante 1 "94252688" "Estela" (make-fecha 20 5 1993) "calle 4 con cra 2" "3333333")    empty    empty)   empty) 
 (make-árbol-bin 
(make-estudiante 7 "34987678" "Juan" (make-fecha 25 3 1995) "calle 34 con cra 12" "6666666")   empty 
 empty) 
)
```

List identification

```
(list "94252688" "94888888")
```

It should return the following list:

```
(list (make-estudiante 1 "94252688" "Estela" (make-fecha 20 5 1993) "calle 4 con cra 2" "3333333") )
```

and I did this but I can not make me return the list

```
(define-struct fecha ( dia mes año))
```

This is the structure of the student:

```
(define-struct estudiante ( codigo id nombre fechanaci direccion telefono))
```

This is the structure of the binary search tree:

```
(define-struct arbol-bin( estudiante nod-izq nod-der))
```

these are the functions that searches the list in the tree

```
(define(buscarevd n E)
(cond
[(or(empty? E) (empty? n))false]
[(equal? (first n)(estudiante-id  E)) true]
 [else (buscarevd (rest n) E)]))

(define(buscare n E)
(cond 
 [(empty? E)false]
[(< (car n)(estudiante-id  E)) true]
 [else false]))


(define (member-bt x bt)
 (cond 
 [(empty? bt) false]
[(or(buscarevd x (arbol-bin-estudiante bt))
[else
(member-bt x (arbol-bin-nod-der bt))]))
```

and this

```
(member-bt (list "94252688" "94888888") tree)
```

return

```
true
```

As I can do to make me return the list.

Comment: You are going to need to show us some effort and what you have tried.

Comment: I did this but I fail to bounce the whole structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if there is some kind of relationship between nodes which would permit you to skip sub-trees here, so I'd use this kind of approach:

```
(define (member-bt lst tree)
   (let loop ((tree tree) (res '()))
     (if (null? tree)
         res
         (let* ((node (árbol-bin-estudiante tree))
                (res1 (loop (árbol-bin-nod-der tree) res))
                (res2 (loop (árbol-bin-nod-izq tree) res1)))
           (if (member (estudiante-id node) lst string=?)
               (cons node res2)
               res2)))))
```

then

```
(let ((lst '("94888888" "34987678" "94252688")))
  (let ((res (member-bt lst tree)))
    (values res (map estudiante-nombre res))))
=>
'(#<estudiante> #<estudiante>)
'("Estela" "Juan")
```

Note that this traverses the tree only once, but the order of the students in the result list is not the same as in the initial list. If order needs to be preserved you need to take a different approach, for example:

```
(define (member-bt-ordered lst tree)
  (define (sub e tree)
    (if (null? tree)
        #f
        (let ((node (árbol-bin-estudiante tree)))
          (if (string=? e (estudiante-id node))
              node
              (or (sub e (árbol-bin-nod-der tree))
                  (sub e (árbol-bin-nod-izq tree)))))))
  (filter values (map (lambda (e) (sub e tree)) lst)))
```

then

```
(let ((lst '( "94252688" "94888888" "35889188" "34987678" "6457234")))
  (let ((res (member-bt-ordered lst tree)))
    (values res (map estudiante-nombre res))))
=> 
'(#<estudiante> #<estudiante> #<estudiante> #<estudiante>)
'("Estela" "Victor" "Juan" "Manuel")
```

Comment: THANKS 

What does the function values

Comment: I use it for 2 things: 1) `(filter values lst)` filters all false values from the list *lst*  2) `(values v1 v2 ...)` returns multiple values (not a list with multiple elements). See for example section 5.8 of http://www.scheme.com/tspl4/control.html

Comment: thanks 

But this is no answer for this question is the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23844221/find-a-list-in-a-binary-tree-scheme?lq=1 
the difference is that the link in question I'm looking for a list in the binary tree and in this question I want to create a binary tree from a list as could do

Comment: You are right. Unfortunately the other question was closed as a duplicate of this one, which is wrong. If you ask to re-open the other one (I will so, too) I can move this answer over again.

Comment: As I can reopen the other question

Comment: Can you help me with this question please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23844221/create-a-binary-tree-from-a-list-of-structures

Comment: as I can write the answer you gave me but intermediate language student